# controller not doing what it should?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have groups which are essentially just tags that can be assigned to different models, through a polymorphic relationship. In model Group I have:

```
def get_members_of(klass)
  self.group_memberships.delete_if {|gm| gm.groupable_type != klass}.map{|g| g.groupable}
end
```

So if I did:

```
group.group_memberships
```

I would get all the objects in group group. However, if I want to limit it to only objects that are instances of model A I would do:

```
group.get_members_of(A)
```

In the console this works exactly as it should. However, I get some unexpected behaviour within my controller:

```
def show
  params[:studies1] = @group.get_members_of('Study').length
  @studies = @group.get_members_of('Study')
  params[:studies2] = @studies.length
  @studies = @group.group_memberships.delete_if {|gm| gm.groupable_type != "Study"}.map{|g| g.groupable}
  params[:studies3] = @studies.length
end
```

As expected params[:studies1] == 1, but studies2 and 3 are == 0. I'm sure I'm missing some small thing...

Comment: Why are you setting the params in your controller?

Comment: A dirty way of seeing the values of each variable, like printf's everywhere.

Comment: easier way to debug that is to use logger.error and then tail -f your log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_members_of function is deeply flawed! When get_members_of is called it removes all other members from group.group_memberships that are not of klass. When the function is called additional times for other "klasses", there are no group_members left...

This works, but looks poor:

```
  def get_members_of(klass)
    x = []
    self.group_memberships.each {|gm| x << gm if gm.groupable_type == klass }
    x.map{|g| g.groupable}
  end
```

Comment: `self.group_memberships.inject([]){|m, el| m << el if el.groupable_type == klass}.map(&:groupable)` is a one liner.